# PHP - strstr function problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, strstr

Good day to all. I am using zend+smarty, but I don't think the framework has any thing to do with the problem. I have the following scenario:

```
     A script that gets a string from a specified site using an api. The string is retrieved corectly so I'll just assign a string to a variable:

     $string = 'String retrieved from api.';
     $string = strstr($string, "<?xml", false);

     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($body);
```

Sounds ok, looks ok. Now the problem.

When I use that on our local test machine it works like a dream. No problem at all. On the other hand, on the production machine I get this:

Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in /home/prj/include/DatabaseObject/Ctrl.php on line 720 (this is the strstr line).

I checked the strings before strstr on the 2 machines and they are identical. Also on the second server after the strstr line the string becomes empty (on the other one it is correctly transformed).

I really don't get it... the code is the same. The string is the same. Is a bit strange to me.

Comment: Do you have the same php version on both?

Comment: Did you compare versions of PHP?  Are PHP.ini identical between the two machines?

Comment: You got a point here... give me a moment.

Comment: You are right... on the server that is working php version is 5.3.3, on the other one is 5.2.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third paramater "before needle" - a boolean value - was added in php 5.3. It's likely your production server is running an earlier version.

see [PHP.net](http://php.net/strstr)

`strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ] )`

- 5.3.0  Added the optional parameter before_needle.